# Speed up PostgreSQL COUNT request with ORDER BY and multiple INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, performance, count, sql-order-by

I have a "complex" request, **used from a back office only** (2 users), that takes around 5s to perform. I would like to know if there are some tips to reduce this delay.

- There are **5M records** in each table.
- `optimized_all` is a varchar and it has a BTREE index.
- **The ORDER BY seems to be the main cause of the delay**. When I remove it, it's 80ms...
- The website is on a dedicated server.
- `work_men` is currently set to 10Mb on the postgresl.conf

**The request**:

```
SELECT
    optimized_all,
    COUNT(optimized_all) AS count_optimized_all
FROM
    "usr_drinks"
    INNER JOIN usr_seasons ON usr_seasons.drink_id = usr_drinks.id
    INNER JOIN usr_photos ON usr_photos.season_id = usr_seasons.id
        AND(usr_photos.verified_kind = 1
            OR usr_photos.verified_kind = 0)
WHERE 
(usr_drinks.optimized_type_id = 1
    AND usr_drinks.optimized_status = 1
    AND usr_seasons.verified_at IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY
    usr_drinks.optimized_all
ORDER BY
    count_optimized_all DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**Explain Analyze**:

```
Limit  (cost=150022.12..150022.12 rows=1 width=194) (actual time=4813.137..4923.631 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=150022.12..150111.98 rows=35945 width=194) (actual time=4813.136..4923.629 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(usr_drinks.optimized_all)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=144716.68..149842.39 rows=35945 width=194) (actual time=3675.407..4881.022 rows=314695 loops=1)
              Group Key: usr_drinks.optimized_all
              ->  Gather Merge  (cost=144716.68..149297.46 rows=37096 width=101) (actual time=3675.400..4799.409 rows=462144 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 4
                    Workers Launched: 4
                    ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=143716.62..143878.91 rows=9274 width=101) (actual time=3647.837..3914.241 rows=92429 loops=5)
                          Group Key: usr_drinks.optimized_all
                          ->  Sort  (cost=143716.62..143739.80 rows=9274 width=93) (actual time=3647.828..3867.945 rows=161362 loops=5)
                                Sort Key: usr_drinks.optimized_all
                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 18848kB
                                Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 16016kB
                                Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 16016kB
                                Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 16008kB
                                Worker 3:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 15752kB
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.30..143105.51 rows=9274 width=93) (actual time=12.400..3077.821 rows=161362 loops=5)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..104531.30 rows=48751 width=109) (actual time=1.882..1242.603 rows=172132 loops=5)
                                            ->  Parallel Index Scan using usr_drinks_on_optimized_type_idx on usr_drinks  (cost=0.43..35406.66 rows=44170 width=109) (actual time=0.097..216.641 rows=196036 loops=5)
                                                  Index Cond: (optimized_type_id = 1)
                                                  Filter: (optimized_status = 1)
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 9387
                                            ->  Index Scan using usr_seasons_on_drink_id_idx on usr_seasons  (cost=0.43..1.54 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=980181)
                                                  Index Cond: (drink_id = usr_drinks.id)
                                                  Filter: (verified_at IS NULL)
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                      ->  Index Scan using usr_photos_on_season_id_idx on usr_photos  (cost=0.43..0.78 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=1 loops=860662)
                                            Index Cond: (season_id = usr_seasons.id)
                                            Filter: ((verified_kind = 1) OR (verified_kind = 0))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 1.120 ms
Execution Time: 4927.502 ms
```

**Possible solution ?**:
Storing the count in another table, but for my needs, it seems quite complicate to update the counters. Any new idea is welcome.

**EDIT 1**: I removed the 2 unnecessary INNER JOIN. Now there are only 2.

**EDIT 2**: I tried to replace the last 2 INNER JOIN by a double EXIST condition. I saved only 1 second. (request is now 4 seconds instead of 1)

```
SELECT
    optimized_all,
    COUNT(optimized_all) AS count_optimized_all
FROM
    "usr_drinks"
WHERE (usr_drinks.optimized_type_id = 1
    AND usr_drinks.optimized_status = 1)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        usr_seasons
    WHERE
        usr_seasons.drink_id = usr_drinks.id
        AND usr_seasons.verified_at IS NULL
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                usr_photos
            WHERE
                usr_photos.season_id = usr_seasons.id
                AND(usr_photos.verified_kind = 1
                    OR usr_photos.verified_kind = 0)))
    GROUP BY
        usr_drinks.optimized_all
    ORDER BY
        count_optimized_all DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

**EDIT 3**: the current postgresql.conf settings are:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 6GB
effective_cache_size = 18GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1536MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 10485kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 12
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 6
max_parallel_workers = 12
```

Increasing work_mem, even to 256MB, doesn't help (surely because my disk is a SSD) ?

Comment: Is joining to usr_properties & msr_wineries even needed in that query?

Comment: count_optimized_all belonds to witch table ?

Comment: @mshabou It belongs to usr_drinks. I edited my post.

Comment: @LukStorms I can remove them yes, but the delay is quite identical.

Comment: have you tried creating index on: usr_drinks(optimized_type_id, optimized_status) and index on usr_seasons(drink_id) where verified_at is not null

Comment: actualy there is almost no way to optimize this query, since PGSL need's to compute all the result set before filtring on the LIMIT 10

Comment: Have you tried replacing the JOINs with `EXISTS` conditions? It seems strange that you want to count the number of row _after_ joining (which means the number of `usr_drinks` is multiplied by the number of matches.  Also `COUNT(usr_drinks.optimized_all)` can be simplified to `count(*)` which is also _slightly_ faster

Comment: @mshabou Adding an index to usr_seasons.verified_at didn't speed ut the request. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i thing that the suggestion of @a_horse_with_no_name is good ,   joining on msr_wineries and on usr_properties is use less, it is only a filtring join, mais be you can change it en EXISTS

Comment: I can remove totally the joining on msr_wineries and usr_properties. The delay is quite the same. However, removin the 2 other joins usr_seasons and usr_photos gives me a x4 speed, but I need them. I will see how to use EXISTS instead ?

Comment: "The ORDER BY seems to be the main cause of the delay"  That is like saying "Wanting the correct answer is the cause of the delay".  If you don't care what the answer is, then just do `select 3;` and watch it fly.

Comment: @jjanes OK, I removed the 2 unnecessary JOINS from the initial post. You can keep cool. I don't want a solution, I just wanted suggestions, I tried many things from my side before asking. Thanks.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?  Has everything been vacuumed and analyzed recently? do you know why the central scan estimate is off by 4 fold? `[estimated] rows=44170 ... actual ... rows=196036`

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is the major contributor to the runtime. It has to sort 161362  rows to discard 68933 of those. And that sorting is done on disk which obviously is slow. So as long as you need the ORDER BY, your best option is probably to increase `work_mem`

Comment: What percentage of the rows of usr_photos match the `(verified_kind = 1) OR (verified_kind = 0)` condition?  Do you have an index on `(verified_kind, season_id)`?  I think you need to get it to do a hash join to usr_photos, and that index might encourage it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I tried to replace the last 2 INNER JOIN with EXISTS, I saved only 20% of time. I will try the other suggestions now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Increasing work_mem to 256MB (and even more) instead  of 10MB changes nothing in the delay. ;)

Comment: @jjanes 70% of usr_photos are `(verified_kind = 1) OR (verified_kind = 0)` I also tried the multicolumn index you suggested `(verified_kind, season_id)` but no more speed. Note that, yes, removing the condition `(verified_kind = 1) OR (verified_kind = 0)` saves me 50% of the delay.

Comment: This query is not richly parameterized.  Some 1's and 0's and an IS NULL, none of them look like they are likely to get changed to other values. So you aren't going to be running this query hundreds of thousands of times with different parameters.  Why then do you care if it takes 5 seconds to run? How often do you really need to run it?  I ask because, having played around with it for quite a while, I think this is pretty close to optimal already.  You might shave off another second, I don't think you will get it 10 times faster with resorting to a materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find a way to speed up massively the request, due to the `ORDER BY` count delay, this is what I did:

- I created a new table that stores the `optimized_all` field with the corresponding `optimized_all_count` - I didn't want to do this firstly, but it was just a 3 hours work for me.
- I run a task once a day that fill this table with `INSERT...SELECT...` and the long request (it's a rails app)
- Now, I just search in this new table... it's just a few milliseconds of course.

This is completely acceptable for my needs (an admin tool), but could not correspond to other scenarios.
**Thanks to everybody for your suggestions.**

Answer (score 0):

Try creating below partial index on `usr_photos`

```
CREATE INDEX user_photos_session_id_partial_ix
ON usr_photos (season_id) 
WHERE (verified_kind = 1) OR (verified_kind = 0);
```

it should reduce query time by 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Arjun, I will try it. In all cases, anything can't be as speed as my solution using a new table that already contains the count.

Answer (score -1):

You are facing a structural problem of PostGreSQL which is unable to correctly optimize queries of type COUNT or SUM. This is due to PostGreSQL's internal architecture due to the way PostGreSQL handles MVCC (Multi Versioning Concurrency Control).

[Take a look at the article I wrote about it.](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/)

The only way around this problem is to use a materialized view.

Comment: I just read your article. Thanks. I will have a look at the materialized views.

Comment: @alex.bour: this answer is wrong. Your performance problem has nothing to do with the MVCC implementation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course it has. Because PostGreSQL is unable to discard phantom slots of past rows which imposes to read one by one all the rows into the data pages to see if the timestamp of the rows version is passed out or alive. In other RDBMS count is done at the page level (in the header) because there is no phantom rows in the page (like Oracle that uses versionned rows from the transaction log or Microsoft SQL Server that use the tempdb database...)

Comment: There is zero indication in the execution plan that table bloat is the root cause of the performance problem.  You can only deduce that if the plan was created with `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see how many buffers where read compared to the number of rows. And Post**g**reSQL also has a visibility map where this can be detected on a per-page basis - but that's only necessary to decide if an Index Only Scan can be used instead of an Index Scan. As can clearly be seen in the execution plan the `ORDER BY` is the culprit here because it has to sort on disk.

Comment: This is not the bloating problem that cause this bad performances but the fact that PostGreSQL is forced to read each row of a page one after the other, while other professionnal RDBMS reads only one single information in the page header to do so.